# How do I enable quicker startup option -A in my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like `-A` flag to be enabled by default. Is there a way to do this in my.cnf? I'm working on `MariaDB 10.0.38`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disabling rehash just add the following line to your configuration file

```
[client-mariadb]
auto-rehash=0
```